# Getting an error when trying to check path

Tags: go

I am trying to check `windows` dir in my golang app.
Here is my code

```
func createWalletDirectory(path string) (err error) {
    _, err = os.Stat(path)

    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return err
    }

    path = filepath.FromSlash(path)

    path = path + string(os.PathSeparator) + DirectoryName

    err = os.Mkdir(path, 0666)

    return
}
```

So on the first line of the function I am getting an error look like this

> invalid character 'i' in string escape code

Example path : `C:\Users`

Note: The path I am getting from users via POST request
So I need to make a code which will check crossplatform paths.
How can I solve this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go strings enclosed by double quotes, a backslash starts an escape code, e.g. `\n` or `\u2318`. To avoid this, you have two options:

- use a double backslash (`\\`), e.g. `"C:\\Users"`
- use backticks (`` ` ``) instead of double quotes to define a "raw string", e.g. `` `C:\Users` ``

[Further reading](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `path` package to work with the urls('`path/filepath`' for the file paths) which also contributes in platform independency. So you can do following to create the path

```
givenPath = filepath.Join(DirectoryName, path)
```

There is also another way of doing this

```
path := strings.Join([]string{DirectoryName, path}, string(os.PathSeparator))
```